# Established OpenVPN connection but cannot access to server

Tags: networking, openvpn

I have established a connection to a OpenVPN network. But I cannot access to the private server

```
Sun Mar  9 17:29:01 2014 [OpenVPN_Server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]37.35.80.126:1194
Sun Mar  9 17:29:04 2014 SENT CONTROL [OpenVPN_Server]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Sun Mar  9 17:29:04 2014 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,explicit-exit-notify,topology subnet,route-delay 5 30,dhcp-pre-release,dhcp-renew,dhcp-release,route-metric 101,ping 12,ping-restart 50,redirect-private def1,redirect-private bypass-dhcp,redirect-private autolocal,route-gateway 10.5.1.129,route 83.150.74.168,route 83.150.67.96 255.255.255.224,route 188.117.16.96 255.255.255.224,route 188.117.20.0 255.255.255.224,route 10.5.1.0 255.255.255.0,route 10.5.2.0 255.255.255.0,route 192.168.0.0 255.255.0.0,dhcp-option DNS 10.5.1.1,dhcp-option DOMAIN xxx.fi,register-dns,auth-token SESS_ID_bRgIOkKTCzXSub9WERmKew==,comp-lzo no,ifconfig 10.5.1.244 255.255.255.128'
Sun Mar  9 17:29:04 2014 Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:4: dhcp-pre-release (2.2.1)
Sun Mar  9 17:29:04 2014 Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:5: dhcp-renew (2.2.1)
Sun Mar  9 17:29:04 2014 Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:6: dhcp-release (2.2.1)
Sun Mar  9 17:29:04 2014 Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:23: register-dns (2.2.1)
Sun Mar  9 17:29:04 2014 Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:24: auth-token (2.2.1)
Sun Mar  9 17:29:04 2014 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Sun Mar  9 17:29:04 2014 OPTIONS IMPORT: explicit notify parm(s) modified
Sun Mar  9 17:29:04 2014 OPTIONS IMPORT: LZO parms modified
Sun Mar  9 17:29:04 2014 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Sun Mar  9 17:29:04 2014 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Sun Mar  9 17:29:04 2014 OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
Sun Mar  9 17:29:04 2014 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
Sun Mar  9 17:29:04 2014 ROUTE default_gateway=192.168.2.1
Sun Mar  9 17:29:04 2014 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Sun Mar  9 17:29:04 2014 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Sun Mar  9 17:29:04 2014 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Sun Mar  9 17:29:04 2014 /sbin/ifconfig tun0 10.5.1.244 netmask 255.255.255.128 mtu 1500 broadcast 10.5.1.255
Sun Mar  9 17:29:09 2014 /sbin/route add -net 37.35.80.126 netmask 255.255.255.255 gw 192.168.2.1
Sun Mar  9 17:29:09 2014 /sbin/route add -net 83.150.74.168 netmask 255.255.255.255 gw 10.5.1.129 metric 101
Sun Mar  9 17:29:09 2014 /sbin/route add -net 83.150.67.96 netmask 255.255.255.224 gw 10.5.1.129 metric 101
Sun Mar  9 17:29:09 2014 /sbin/route add -net 188.117.16.96 netmask 255.255.255.224 gw 10.5.1.129 metric 101
Sun Mar  9 17:29:09 2014 /sbin/route add -net 188.117.20.0 netmask 255.255.255.224 gw 10.5.1.129 metric 101
Sun Mar  9 17:29:09 2014 /sbin/route add -net 10.5.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.5.1.129 metric 101
Sun Mar  9 17:29:09 2014 /sbin/route add -net 10.5.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.5.1.129 metric 101
Sun Mar  9 17:29:09 2014 WARNING: potential route subnet conflict between local LAN [192.168.2.0/255.255.255.0] and remote VPN [192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0]
Sun Mar  9 17:29:09 2014 /sbin/route add -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 10.5.1.129 metric 101
Sun Mar  9 17:29:09 2014 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

There is a warning:  `WARNING: potential route subnet conflict between local LAN [192.168.2.0/255.255.255.0] and remote VPN [192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0]`

But I don't understand this message. Could you please tell me a hint or a solution for this problem?

Comment: 192.168.2.0 is included in 192.168.0.0/16 and thus you are saying, there are *two* default gateways for 192.168.2.0. One in your local LAN and one in your VPN. So, where should the computer send a package for this network?

BTW, you seem to push a lot of of routes. Maybe you want to post your OpenVPN server conf?

Comment: Can you help me how to diagnose the health of the connection?